# Strange behaviour of $\Gamma$-function

Tags: renormalization

on the Wikipedia article of the $\Gamma$-function it says that it fulfills the following property:

$$z \Gamma(z) = \Gamma(z+1)$$

on its entire domain. Now consider the following case

$$\Gamma(3-x) \Gamma(x+3) \overset{x \rightarrow 0}{\longrightarrow} \Gamma(3)\Gamma(3)= 2! 2! = 4$$

However, with the above property we could also do this:

$$\Gamma(3-x) \Gamma(3+x)= \Gamma(3-x)\Gamma(3+x) = \Gamma(3-x)x \Gamma(2+x)=-(-x)\Gamma(3-x)\Gamma(3+x)$$

And now for the term, factor, we can use:

$$(-x)\Gamma(3-x)=\left . z\Gamma(3+z) \right|_{z=-x}=\left.\Gamma(4+z) \right|_{z=-x}=\Gamma(4-x).$$

Plugging back in yields:

$$-\Gamma(4-x)\Gamma(3+x) \rightarrow -\Gamma(4)\Gamma(3) = -6 \times2= -12.$$

Am I misinterpreting somthing or so? Where am I wrong?

Comment: This is a check-my-work type question and will likely be closed. You have at least one simple error (see my answer).

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 2):

> However, with the above property we could also do this:

> $$\Gamma(3-x) \Gamma(3+x)= \Gamma(3-x)\Gamma(3+x) = \Gamma(3-x)x \Gamma(2+x)=-(-x)\Gamma(3-x)\Gamma(3+x)$$

You are at least going wrong here:

> $\Gamma(3-x)\Gamma(3+x) = \Gamma(3-x)x \Gamma(2+x)$

Which should read:
$$
\Gamma(3-x)\Gamma(3+x) = \Gamma(3-x)(2+x) \Gamma(2+x)
$$